# MySQL select where timenow > database time

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, statements

I have a PHP script which creates a new order and inserts the time NOW + 15 minutes into the database.

After 15 minutes have expired the user cannot access the order page.

On the admin panel I only want to show records that have not expired, so my question is what select statement would I use to do this, and which would be the most efficent?

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE datenow > date
```

The "date" is the date of the order + 15 minutes

**P.S.
Aternativly, is there any way to do this using PHP so I don't have to put too much stress on the database?**

Many Thanks!

Comment: I tend to use bigints and store timestamps, instead of using the databases datetime functions. This allows for easier readability (for me at least lol) and manipulation by timestamp (int). Since selecting by ranges > and < is pretty straightforward by the second.

Comment: I would just like to know what the SQL query would be to do this? As my query is of course wrong

Comment: You'll want to exclude the orders in MySQL instead of PHP because eventually you may have 1000 expired orders in the DB but only 1 active one - you don't want to have to return 1001 rows from MySQL just to loop through and grab that 1 in PHP. (unless you're periodically cleaning up that table somehow)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that you want records that have not yet expired, you want all records where `date` is greater than [`NOW()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now).

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    `orders` 
WHERE 
    `date` > NOW()
```

As the comments mentioned, it is usually better to handle this on the database side; rather than transfer (assuming you have split database and web servers) the entire data set to filter it in the application code.

The other benefit of having all the datetime functions be on the same server (in the database in this case), is that especially on some shared hosting environments, the timezone for the database cannot be changed. Therefore, you want the time comparisons to occur in the same timezone.

Comment: Good point about the timezone. If php and mysql are not set the same, it can cause serious headaches ;)

Comment: PERFECT, exactly what I was looking for, I will select this as the answer

Comment: Oh... And tell me about the headaches of them not being in the same timezone, I have had to deal with this problem plenty of times

Comment: Would you say this is practically the most efficient method?

Comment: I can't think of anything else that would be more efficient, other than having a job that flagged orders as expired so it wouldn't have to do a datetime comparison but rather check for a `expired = 1` but that does require ensuring that the job runs at an appropriate interval. Or for that matter, moving those records to an "expired" table; but that would likely cause all sorts of other problems.